# How to populate static members of recurring template derived class?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, crtp

I have this class (bare bones version):

```
class Background : public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        static const QMetaObject *index(const QString &name) { return m_indexes.value(name, nullptr); }
        static const QList<QString> names() { return m_indexes.keys(); } }

    protected:
        explicit Background(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

    private:
        static const QMap<QString, const QMetaObject *> m_indexes;
};
```

Because i will have few other classes with the exact same base structure, polymorphism was obvious but what i need is the `static const m_indexes` to be unique for each derived class, i found out that i could use recurring template to do what i need, but i can't find out how to "populate" my unique static const members at compile time.

```
template<class T>
class Base {
    // ...
    static const QMap<QString, const QMetaObject *> m_indexes;
}

template<class T> const QMap<QString, const QMetaObject *> Base<T>::m_indexes;
```

This is what i got from CRTP, but it will initialize them all the same way, how can i, in each derived class, have `m_indexes` having unique entries.?

Something along the lines of:

```
class Background : public QObject, public Base<Background>
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Background (QObject *parent = nullptr) : 
            QObject(parent), Base<Background>() {}    
};

const QMap<QString, const QMetaObject *> Base<Background>::m_indexes = {
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the static variables, so yes, for each type, you need to define it with:

```
const QMap<QString, const QMetaObject *> Base<Background>::m_indexes = {/**/};
```

Just declaring the template `m_indexes` doesn't instantiate the symbol, same old issue with templates!

Comment: But where am i supposed to do that ? because i tried and i could not make it work.

Comment: In a cpp file, you need to define all these `m_indexes`.

Comment: Alright it is working, thanks a lot. I was so close and yet i could not make it work, so infuriating :)